# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, sockets

I'm trying to work with MySQL on Linux. It was working fine before but somehow I messed it up. Now whenever I type in #mysql it just give me the error in the title. I did tons of research on this topic, some said it's the problem with my.cnf. So I tried to locate that file in /etc/MySQL/my.cnf. But the strange thing is on my machine, the file is located in /usr. And not only it's located in a different directory, the content of it is also strange.

```
[mysqld]    

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....
# socket = .....

# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

And some other websites said that I should check if MySQL is running or not. And whenever I type

/etc/init.d/mysql status

it just says -bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory.

After countless tries, I decided I'll just reinstall MySQL. I followed the directions on [this](http://tecadmin.net/remove-mysql-completely-from-linux-system/) site. But the same problems occurs when it's done.

So did I install MySQL in the wrong directory? Or is something wrong with my.cnf? Someone please help because I've been stuck here for over 2 weeks and still can't get a clue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Linux is, unlike windows, a case-sensitive environment. It should be `/etc/init.d/mysql` not `/etc/init.d/MySQL`. Questions not in programing scope don't belong to Stackoverflow. Consider asking on Superuser.

Comment: oh sorry the web browser automatically changed mysql into MySQL. I'm sure that I typed in all lower case. I'll fix it right now. But thanks for the commenting :)

Comment: What flavor of Linux, and how did you install mysql? It looks like the init script isn't there.